# Why can't I index variables in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If dictionary is ordered in Python 3.6+, why can't I call a dictionary variable as `print(dictionary_name[index])`?

Got error.

Comment: Because it's still not _semantically_ ordered, and what would you expect for `{1: "foo", 0: "bar"}[0]`?!

Comment: Because, the designers of the `dict` API decided that you shouldn't be able to do that. And it makes a lot of sense. `int` keys are totally valid, so how would `({1:'a', 0: 'b'})[0]` distinguish between *the first value* or the *the value that corresponds to the key `0`*? Now, they could have addded some method to retrieve key/values using positional indices, but they didn't. As to *why* they didn't, probably because they saw no good reason to.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga or the first _key_, even, given it's the 0th value in the context of iterating over the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but the following might be what you're looking for.

```
print(list(dictionary_name.values())[index])
```

This definitely feels like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory, as I'm not sure *why* you'd want to do this.